# Load data to WebView in background without open Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview

I need load in background html-page in WebView in Activity. Only real background without open Activity.
I try use `moveTaskToBack( true);` in onCreate. But this is does not always correct, Activity sometimes opens.
What is best way load data to WebView in background?
p.s. my real task: load data from URL in background with javascript-injections (in my Widget).